# Closure of image is subset of image of closure

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a bounded set and $f$ be a continuous function,  $ f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$. How do I show that $\overline{f(A)} \subset f(\overline{A})$?

What I have tried so far: $A \subset \overline{A}$, so $f(A) \subset f(\overline{A})$ and $\overline{f(A)} \subset \overline{f(\overline{A})}$. Since, $A$ is bounded we have a closed ball $B$ such that $A \subset B$. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try expanding the body of the question a bit with your thoughts. It will make it more clear to people how this differs from the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument would be complete if you can show that $\overline{f(\overline{A})}=f(\overline{A})$, i.e. that $f(\overline{A})$ is closed. Certainly, $\overline{A}$ is closed, but continuous functions need not take closed sets to closed sets. However, they must take compact sets to compact sets and compact sets are closed. Is $\overline{A}$ compact? Hint: Heine-Borel.